# Axios POST does not recognize the data being passed in from react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am already making a restful API using nodejs on the backend, here is my folder structure :

```
├── server
│   ├── project.controller.js
│   ├── auth.js
│   └── project.routes.js
│   └── project.model.js
├── client
│   └── AddProjectModal.js
│   └── axios.service.js
│   └── auth-header.js
```

the server api seems working fine because i can perform CRUD actions using postman, however if i try to send post request from the client side which is react, i somehow unable to proceed. I tried self-debugging for hours using the console.log to figure out where i did wrong but i couldn't find something.

Here is my AddProjectModal.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { authAxios } from "../../services/axios.service";

const AddProjectModal = ({ isShow, isClose }) => {
  const [newProject, setNewProject] = useState({
    title: "",
    type: "",
    description: "",
    //thumbnail: "",
  });

  const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", newProject.title);
    formData.append("type", newProject.type);
    formData.append("description", newProject.description);
    // formData.append("thumbnail", newProject.thumbnail);
    console.log(...formData);
    try {
      await authAxios
        .post("/api/project/", formData)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

.... 
}
```

as you can see i tried to console.log(...formData) to see if the data is successfully appended, and it did. Here is the example result :

[image: result from console.log(...formData)]

Heres my axios.service.js code :

```js
import axios from "axios";
import authHeader from "./auth-header";

const apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/";

export const authAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiUrl,
  headers: authHeader(),
});

export const publicAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiUrl,
});
```

my auth-header.js code:

```js
const authHeader = () => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

  if (user && user.accessToken) {
    return { "x-access-token": user.accessToken };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
};

export default authHeader;
```

And there are my backend code :

project.routes.js :

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");
const controller = require("../../controllers/project.controller");

//Upload new project
router.post("/", auth, controller.createProject);


module.exports = router;
```

project.controller.js :

```js
const Project = require("../models/project.model");
// create & save new project
exports.createProject = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.body.title || !req.body.type || !req.body.description) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Form cant be empty!" });
    return;
  }

  try {
    //create project
    const project = new Project({
      title: req.body.title,
      type: req.body.type,
      description: req.body.description,
    });
    // save project to the database
    const createdProject = await project.save();
    res.send(createdProject);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err" + err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
    next(err);
  }
};
```

On code above im trying to console.log(req.body) to see if the data is being passed in , when im using postman to post request i get this result :
[image]

and here is the result when im requesting from the browser, i got empty object :

[image]

Since i am able to make request from Postman, i dont think the problem is on my server side, here is the result when im trying to make post request from browser :
[image]

Comment: first of all you should send the res as json like `res.json({}) ` and also in your catch block you shouldn't send a response any more because as far as i can see you are using an error handler middleware( next(err) ) and also i think you have cors policy issue console log the error  in front see if you get cors policy issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explain

- Why it works on Postman and not on the client code?

The difference is the **format** of the request. In Postman, you're sending the data as JSON object. While in the client code, you're sending data inside a form-data. They are different. That's why the `req.body` is empty. **Different request formats require the server to parse in different ways**.

### Action

I see in your code the line `//formData.append("thumbnail", newProject.thumbnail);` is commented, you prepare to send the project's thumbnail in the request. In this case, you cannot send the request in JSON format. You need to modify the server to make it understand the form data.

For this, I recommend this [popular package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

> Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which
> is primarily used for uploading files.

Comment: I figured it out after reading your suggestion that the form need to be handled differently, i ended up using the react-hooks-form for the validation and i successfully sent it to my database !

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) library. Editing my AddProjectModal.js like so :

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import { authAxios } from "../../services/axios.service";

const AddProjectModal = ({ isShow, isClose }) => {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      type: "",
      description: "",
      thumbnail: "",
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await authAxios
        .post("/api/project/", data)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <Modal show={isShow === "modal-one"} onHide={isClose}>
      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>Tambahkan Project</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <form encType="multipart/form-data">
          <Form.Group controlId="title">
            <Form.Label>Judul Project</Form.Label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="title"
              render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Nama Project"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="type">
            <Form.Label>Jenis Projek : </Form.Label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="type"
              render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                <Form.Control as="select" onChange={onChange} value={value}>
                  <option value=""> </option>
                  <option value="web apps">Web Apps</option>
                  <option value="mobile apps">Mobile Apps</option>
                  <option value="landing page">Landing Page</option>
                </Form.Control>
              )}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="description">
            <Form.Label>Deskripsi Projek</Form.Label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="description"
              render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                <Form.Control
                  as="textarea"
                  rows={3}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <label>Foto Anda</label>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="thumbnail"
              render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                <Form.File
                  type="file"
                  id="thumbnail"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </form>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          Upload
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={isClose}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AddProjectModal;
```

for me the problem was my previous form wont sent the data that being inputed in. After using react-hook-form , basically i store all the data that being passed into the {control} ( because i use custom component react-bootstrap ) , if you using normal form you can use {register} instead!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

as Dang Khoa said , he suggested to install multer for handling form-data type. If you dont want to use react-hooks-form , you can still handle form-data type by installing multer and editing your index.js / app.js on your server fire to include multer :

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors"); // this
const multer = require("multer");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const upload = multer();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(upload.array()); // and this
//cors
```